# Units conversion Box2D with weird results

Tags: libgdx, box2d

i'm using LibGDX and trying to learn box2D, but this units conversions are confusing me, what i think: i got a 256x256 pixels image and want to create a body representing this image, using the 1:32 scale, so everytime i want to pass values to the box2D scale i must divide it by 32 or mutiply by 1/32(it's the same equation), and everytime i want to get values from this world to pixel scale i must mutiply it by 32, but the problems still the same: can't get good simulations, i'll put my code here for you see how i'm doing things(i'll put the variables too so you can just ctrl+c and ctrl+v):

```
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private ShapeRenderer srender;
    private Texture img;

    private World world;
    private Body bad, bridge;

    private OrthographicCamera cam, cam2;

    private Box2DDebugRenderer render;
@Override
public void create () {
        srender = new ShapeRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

        cam = new OrthographicCamera(500f, 500f);
        cam.translate(250f, 250f);
        cam.update();

        //Used to draw the box2D world scaled to the pixels size
        cam2 = new OrthographicCamera(500 * 0.03125f, 500 * 0.03125f);
        cam2.translate(250f * 0.03125f, 250f * 0.03125f);
        cam2.update();

        render = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        world = new World(new Vector2(0f, -10f), true);

        BodyDef bdef = new BodyDef();
        bdef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bad = world.createBody(bdef);

        PolygonShape pshape = new PolygonShape();
        pshape.setAsBox(img.getWidth() * 0.03125f, img.getHeight() * 0.03125f);

        FixtureDef fdef = new FixtureDef();
        fdef.shape = pshape;
        bad.createFixture(fdef);

        /*Criando a ponte*/
        bdef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        bridge = world.createBody(bdef);

        pshape.setAsBox(500f * 0.03125f, 5f * 0.03125f);
        bridge.createFixture(fdef);

        bad.setTransform(new Vector2(250f * 0.03125f, 500f * 0.03125f) , 0);
        bridge.setTransform(new Vector2(250f * 0.03125f, 0f * 0.03125f), 0);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        srender.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    }

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, (bad.getPosition().x - img.getWidth()/2 * 0.03125f) * 32, 
                            (bad.getPosition().y - img.getHeight()/2 * 0.03125f) * 32);
            batch.end();

            render.render(world, cam2.combined);

            srender.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
            srender.circle(250f, 500f, 5f);
            srender.circle(250f, 0f, 5f);
            srender.end();

            world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);
}
```

if you run this code you will see that the box created still not fitting the image size, the image stop walking on the middle of the screen while it should stop only at the bottom, can anyone help me here? thanks for attention.

Ps:i have already heard about changing the viewport, but i'm still trying to learn this conversions, after that i'll go look for the viewports.

Comment: have a look at http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels

Comment: You really should look at @Xoppa s blog. Unfortunately some tutorials out there use some kind of Pixel-to-Unit-conversion. But libgdx already has a tool that does this for you: `Viewport`. So instead of converting the pixels yourself you should let the `Viewport`s do that for you!